# Python psycopg2 PostgreSQL attemp to deallocate

Tags: python, postgresql, prepared-statement, psycopg2

I wanted to know if it's possible to attempt to deallocate a PostgreSQL prepared statement before trying to open it

at the moment I am using the following code to deallocate all prepared statements

```
cur_deallocate = gv_pgsql.cursor()
cur_deallocate.execute("deallocate all")

cur_users = gv_pgsql.cursor()
cur_users.execute("prepare cur_users as " +
                  "select * from users")
```

this works however if there is another prepared statement that I still need in a separate function then it will be closed as well. However if I use deallocate cur_users then the program will crash with the error that it can't deallocate a prepared statement that doesn't exist.

Is there a way around this? to attempt to deallocate and if it fails then prepare the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the error in an except block, or see if it exists first using pg_prepared_statements view: [enter link description here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/view-pg-prepared-statements.html)
In our installation statement names are stored in lower case

```
def safe_deallocate(self, statement_name):
    curs.execute(
        "select true from pg_prepared_statements where name = lower(%s)", (statement_name,))
    if curs.rowcount:
        curs.execute("deallocate {}".format(statement_name))
```